# How to fetch data from multiple tables using where class in NotORM?

Tags: notorm

How to fetch data from multiple tables using where class in `NotORM`?

**CODE**

```
SELECT tbl1.description,
concat(tbl2.first_name, ' ', + tbl2.last_name) name,
count(tbl3.description)
FROM table1 tbl1, table3 tbl3,table2 tbl2
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl3.s_id
and tbl1.value= tbl2.value
group by tbl1.description,name
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, simply you can try like this

```
$db->table1()->select("description,(SELECT first_name FROM table2 where table2.value=table1.value)as firstname")->group("description")->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

NotORM is designed to work with well-named tables and columns. The default naming convention  would lead to this kind of request (if I guess your need right):

```
SELECT table1.description,
    CONCAT(table2.first_name, ' ', + table2.last_name) name,
    COUNT(table3.description)
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.id = table3.table1_id
  AND table2.id = table1.table2_id
GROUP BY table1.description, name
```

In notOrm

```
$db->table1()
  ->select("table3.description")
  ->select("CONCAT(table2.first_name, ' ', + table2.last_name) AS name")
  ->select("COUNT(table3.description) AS c")
  ->group("table1.description, name");
```

There is no need to join these tables together. It's NotOrm's job.